# RabbitMQ best practice to handle exceptions when process a message asynchronously

Tags: rabbitmq

Registered a **async** consumer of rabbitmq message. 
Didn't get official suggestions how to handle the process exception in async consumer action?
Maybe need retry the queue message /republish the message to the queue with a retry times limitation.

Answer (score 0):

When consuming from a queue in rabbitMq you can set an option called noAck that can be true or false.

- `true` it will ack a message in the event of an error it cannot handle
- `false` will automatically nack the message and will stay in the
  queue to be pulled later.

*(This will depend on the language you are using for your consumer. noAck = nodejs, autoAck = c#, etc.)*

```
consumer.consume(q.queue, function (message) {
    // your code
}, {noAck: false});
```

In regards to setting limited retries, I had to do this myself by passing the retry count in the header of the message I was passing and had to ack the message I was reading before sending the new version with the modified header back to the queue. I used multiple queues in order to maintain message integrity but this could be done with one queue.

I hope this has helped.